# dose regex in Android are the same as regex in Java?

Tags: java, android, regex

I wrote a code in Java to out cast regexp pattern from a string , the program work. Then I copy that code to my Android program (that doing the same as my Java program) but mach.find() don't find anything.
Dose there is any adjustment that I need to do?

Here is the String that I`m working on (A Web-page)

And this is the function that I`m running - get a String (the Web page), pattern, and Boolean (if to DOTALL or not):

```
 private int getNumberOfShows(String resultStr, String pattern, boolean newLine) {

        Pattern exp;
        if (newLine)
            exp = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
        else
            exp = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher match = exp.matcher(resultStr);
        int count = 0;
        while (match.find()) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

The Pattern is: `"eater/\\d*?/\\\">(\\W*?)</a>(.*?)f=\"/showtimes/th?"/`
The Boolean is : `True`.

I want to count The number of the pattern occurrences.

Thanks.

Comment: You can test your [java regexp online](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). And there are a lot of helpfull online and offline services to debug your regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's the same.

You can read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).